# Stop a service from starting when it is disabled in the rc.d

Tags: startup, services, dhcpd

I am running a minimal Ubuntu 13.04 on a BeagleBone. I try to disable `udhcpd` permanently, but I do not want to remove it. I want to be able to enable it when/if I need it. I have removed it from the rc.d by executing `sudo update-rc.d -f udhcpd remove` and I even cross verified that by installing and running `sysv-rc-conf`. After doing that, if I reboot, everything seems to work properly. I execute `ps -e | grep udhcpd` to verify that `udhcpd` hasn't started and indeed I get nothing. **However**, when I shutdown the system and turn it back on, `udhcpd` is back on! Any ideas on what and why is going on and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no clue on ***why*** this is happening, but a non-elegant solution that worked, i.e. killed all the instances of `udhcpd` at login was to write a simple bash script that locates the process IDs of the `udhcpd` and calls `kill` on them:

1. Create a script file in `/etc/profile.d/`: e.g. `my_file.sh`
2. In `my_file.sh` write the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   TST=$(pgrep udhcpd) 
   echo "So udhcpd has the following PIDs" 
   echo $TST 
   # put one PID in each element of the array, i.e split on the spaces 
   arr=($TST) 
   for i in "${arr[@]}" 
   do 
       echo "We are now going to execute kill -9 $i" 
       sudo kill -9 $i 
   done 
   echo "Done."
   ```
3. Make the file executable: `chmod +x /etc/profile.d/my_file.sh`
4. Shutdown, power on and next time you login this script (asking you for root password) should be executed.
5. After logging in, execute:

   ```
   pgrep udhcpd
   ```

   just to make sure that all of the instances have been killed.

Comment: just set option DHCPD_ENABLED="no" in /etc/default/udhcpd